# How do I install 'proper' anti-virus protection for Online Banking satisfying its Terms of Use?

Tags: antivirus

I am using 64 bit Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. So far I have not been able to install well known antivirus software:

- ClamTk seems to suffer from lots of false positives.
- Bitdefender is a nuisance. Sometimes it is there then it seems to be gone.
- Avast seems to be of poor quality according to my system that is. Also it does not support 64 bit as far as I know.
- Avira antivir warns: 'This script has to be run as root' althoug I am certain that I am running it as root.

So now I am stuck.

FYI: I would like to install antivirus software to avoid discussions with my bank since  I use online banking. Dutch banks are demanding 'proper' antivirus software to be installed in their Terms Of Use and will refuse any refunds in case you are the victim of phishing/malware if you can't proof you had installed it

Thanks so much in advance.

Hans

Comment: Do you happen to come from the Netherlands where banks are demanding 'proper' antivirus software to be installed in their Terms Of Use and will refuse any refunds in case you are the victim of phishing/malware if you can't proof you had installed it? If so, add this to your question, as it's likely to be closed-for-duplicate.

Comment: Oh, and please include what statements these AV-vendors are making about support on Ubuntu. It's kinda different from other Linux distributions in terms of security (i.e. Apparmor).

Comment: Can't  you just imstall any virus scan and not turn it on?
It says you need a av installed, but what about turning it on?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to this:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=622967

I have succeeded installing AVG free.

But now there is no gui.,,,,

Also I have to start it manually and I am not sure if it is scanning on demand, although it says so.

Actually I am getting a bit fed up with this. I have changed my OS for security reasons and now it appears to be virtually impossible to install a realtime virusscanner.

People will most likely say: 'There is no need vor a virusscanner in Linux' but Dutch banks do not think so I quess.

Comment: I hope Dutch banks will see the light some day. A Live Linux CD/DVD to do banking is far more secure than demanding people to keep using Windows for an OS-independent website. [Germans are doing better at this](http://www.heise.de/ct/projekte/Sicheres-Online-Banking-mit-Bankix-284099.html).